How to make Python VSCode Intellisense work with dynamically imported versioned API modules
I have a Python client library that supports multiple versions of a server by dynamically loading a different "API" module depending on which version of the server is connected to.
Once that module is loaded, the API content is fully determined. The implementing class has complete comments and even has full type hinting implemented. However, because it is dynamically loaded, the type information is lost in VSCode and someone developing against the library does not get any of the suggestions and completions that VSCode would give with other Python code. (I have the Python extension installed so I guess this is really a PyLance question?)
Roughly speaking, the actual setup looks something like this:
There is a directory containing the API modules:
    api/
      ver_1/
        api.py
      ver_2/
        api.py
      ...

Each api.py module exposes a "root API" object that is derived from a common generic type - say, api_base.
The client library code looks something like this:
class Client:
    def connect_to_server(...) -> api_base:
        # Depending on the version of the server,
        # use importlib.import_module() to import the correct api.py

Is there any way that VSCode/PyLance can be coerced into assuming that connect_to_server returns a specific type so that Intellisense would work? It would be nice to make this configurable but it wouldn't matter if it was fixed to a specific version - the latest one, say, as this would satisfy the most common use case, and the API versions differ little enough that it would be useful even for users of older versions.
In trying to find others who have had similar issues, I have come across suggestions of using .pyi files, but I haven't quite been able to get my head around exactly what I would need to do, nor indeed be sure whether this is the right solution to be pursuing.
Update
A comment asked me why I couldn't simply use typing.cast. This might in fact offer a solution for certain cases, but I think the point is that we want to avoid any unnecessary explicit mentions of version numbers.
The Intellisense support that I am concerned about is for the users of the Client library, who will typically be writing scripts against the API that it exposes. The API is conceptually simple but is quite big, and it involves a lot of named settings exposed as properties. It would be useful for users if code completions and suggestions worked.
The expectation is that a given version of the client library is associated with a default server version. One detail that I skipped is that it will often launch as well as connect to the default version of the server process. So, the normal use case for 95% of the time is that that current version is going to be used without having to mention it, but there has to be flexibility to use a different version if required. Moreover, if a script is written against version N, there is an expectation that the same script should almost always work without modification against version N+1. We therefore would like to avoid imposing the requirement on users to introduce explicit casts in their code just so that they can get Intellisense to work.
Based on some preliminary experiments, I think I might be able to achieve what I want by using .pyi files in a particular way. I need to take it further and will write a solution if it works out. The basic idea is that the .pyi (but no actual code) will refer explicitly to the current default API version. The typing.cast approach then might be a way for users who explicitly want to use a different version to override that default behaviour.

Could you be a little more specific? How is the Client class is typically used, if not just Client().connect_to_server())? As it is, a simple cast(APIVersion1, ...) would do, but I assume that's not what you are after?

Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to elaborate a little in the question.
